# Gunicorn with django giving 500 with no extra information

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, wsgi

I am trying to run django 3.2.16 with gunicorn, I get this output in console:

```
[2023-01-15 23:45:39 +0100] [210935] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-01-15 23:45:39 +0100] [210935] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2023-01-15 23:45:39 +0100] [210935] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (210935)
[2023-01-15 23:45:39 +0100] [210935] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-01-15 23:45:39 +0100] [210936] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 210936
[2023-01-15 23:45:39 +0100] [210935] [DEBUG] 1 workers
```

Everything looks like working, but when I go to localhost, I get `Internal Server Error`.

It kinda behaves like if I had `DEBUG = False`, but I have `DEBUG = True` and there is also nothing in console. Django setup finishes and I also verify, that settings.DEBUG is indded true:

My wsgi.py file:

```
application = get_wsgi_application()
print(settings.DEBUG)
```

And of course `runserver` works fine.

What else could that be? How to get some kind of error output? I tried `capture-out` and all the log files and levels that gunicorn provides but got nothing useful from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was this line in my django log settings:

```
        "disable_existing_loggers": True,
```

Setting this to `False` fixed my problem.